# Is there a way to create a static Gradient on an animated SVG with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have tried a few different things to get a SVG to have a Gradient background that doesn't move when I animate the SVG.

My first attempt

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  /* Temporary - Used to see the box */
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  /* Temporary - Used to see the box */
}
#container svg {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.parallax > use {
  animation: wave 25s cubic-bezier(.55, .5, .45, .5) infinite;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-duration: 7s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-duration: 13s;
}
.parallax > use:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-duration: 20s;
}
@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-90px, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(85px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <svg class='waves' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 24 150 28' preserveAspectRatio='none' shape-rendering='auto'>
          <defs>
            <path id='wave' d='M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z' />
            <linearGradient id='waveGradient' gradientTransform='rotate(45)'>
              <stop offset='0%'  stop-color='red' />
              <stop offset='100%' stop-color='green' />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <g class='parallax'>
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='0' fill="url('#waveGradient')" opacity='0.7' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='3' fill="url('#waveGradient')" opacity='0.5' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='5' fill="url('#waveGradient')" opacity='0.3' />
            <use xlink:href='#wave' x='48' y='7' fill="url('#waveGradient')" />
          </g>
        </svg>
</div>
```

as you can see, the Gradient moves with the waves.

My second attempt to create it using a clipPath.

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  /* Temporary - Used to see the box */
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red 0%, green 100%);
  /* Temporary - Used to see the box */
  
  clip-path: url(#wavePath);
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  
</div>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="wavePath">
      <path d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

This however results in the viewBox values not being used and doesn't create the correct shape.

I am lost on how this can be done at this point and can use some help figuring it out.

Here is the base SVG Code:

```
<svg>
  <path d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create the effect by animating the gradient and the container at the same but in the opposite direction.

Here is a basic example:

```css
#container  {
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#container > div {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;  
  clip-path: url(#wavePath);
  animation:move 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
#container > div::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow, blue);
  animation:move 2s linear infinite alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    transform:translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
   <div></div>
</div>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="wavePath">
      <path d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Or simply make the wave with solid color moving above gradient:

```css
#container  {
  width:100px;
  height:85px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow, blue);
}

#container > div {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;  
  clip-path: url(#wavePath);
  background:#fff;
  animation:move 2s linear infinite alternate;
}


@keyframes move {
  to {
    transform:translateX(-45%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
   <div></div>
</div>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="wavePath">
      <path d="M-160 44c30 0 58-18 88-18s 58 18 88 18 58-18 88-18 58 18 88 18 v44h-352z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for what I am trying to do. The animation needs to go in a single direction infinitely.

Comment: @8BitDreams you can make it in a single direction, the same trick apply. Any animation that is infinite will restart from the beginning in order to continue infinitely

Comment: Even then, the SVG isn't using the viewBox values so it's not the correct shape.

Comment: @8BitDreams added another idea

Comment: @8BitDreams I am not giving the final result, I am giving ideas that I am trying to illustrate using basic examples. You need to adjust the code to obtain what you want

Comment: I see your idea and how they work but the issue right now that is preventing anything is the clipPath method. Using a clipPath results in an incorrect shape because it doesn't using the Viewbox values from the first example I provided. By the way, thanks for editing my examples. I didn't know they could be presented in that way.